# Two Listviews and a static content between

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Hi guys i am wonder whether it is possible to have a layout similar to the one that i have attached below. I need to have two different Listview with different set of Row items and a static content inbetween this two listviews. I am not sure how to go about this. Your valuable comments are welcomed. Thanks in Advance.[image]

[image]

Problem that i am facing is that i need to give support for this layout for both orientations. So i have wrapped all this controls within a scrollview and there comes the problem for the scrolling. I do know that it is not advisable to use listview within the scrollview but i am wonder how i can go about this. Without Scrollview on the portrait mode its very fine but while on the landscape mode is where i have problem.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? did you try to simply create a vertical LinearLayout containing a ListView, another ViewGroup and a second ListView. Should works fine.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: @Guian I have updated by question and explained what is the problrm that i am facing.